# past continuous, future perfect, past perfect continuous, etc - Are they useful?

Tags: tenses

I'm learning English as a ESL student. In addition, I have never been to English-speaking countries, so I couldn't learn which grammar is no more useful these days. In my memory, I haven't seen any sentences using past continuous tense and future perfect tense in the articles that I read except grammar books. So I wonder these tenses are useful when native users speak or write something or they are just old grammar that few people use.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are useful and current.

*I was walking to work this morning when I met John.*

*I will have finished reading the book by tomorrow.*